# How can I set up a local host with a reasonable name, different than "localhost:80"?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mac, mamp

I find it confusing to work on my site locally when there's something like "localhost:80" in the adress bar. It would be much better to have something like "mydomainoffline.com" which then maps somehow to "localhost:80", if possible. How would I do that on the MAC?

I use the free MAMP package ([mamp.info](http://mamp.info)), not the commercial MAMP PRO. So I need to do that sort of thing by hand. How can I do that?

Comment: You can drop the ":80" as that's the default port assumed by the browser.

Answer (score 7):

I realize that the OP has a mac, and that the solutions given work for both mac and linux.

But I would also like to add that Windows has a hosts file too in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, in case someone comes here through google with the same problem and uses windows :)

Comment: +1 for being nice to non-macists :-)

Answer (score 4):

The Webserver can't do that for you, as it's not responsible for DNS resolution.

You'll need to add an entry to your [Hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file) (`/private/etc/hosts` or `/etc/hosts` depending on the version), and then perform some [special](http://ocaoimh.ie/mac-os-x-how-to-update-etchosts/) [MacOS X](http://codinginparadise.org/weblog/2008/05/changing-mac-os-x-hosts-file.html) [magic ritual](http://kb.wisc.edu/middleware/page.php?id=4506) to make it stick.

Comment: Leopard (10.5) (and presumably 10.6) has no `niload` so I'm not sure if this applies any more.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by editing `/etc/hosts` (you will need to do this as administrator, e.g. `sudo nano /etc/hosts`

Find the line that looks like:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
```

And add another hostname, e.g.

```
127.0.0.1    localhost mydomainoffline.com
```

(Edit: I should point out that while this works just fine for Leopard (10.5), I don't know about other versions of Mac OS X)

Answer (score 1):

Edit your HOSTS file (**/etc/hosts**)
Replace **localhost** by the desired name

*And you don't need to have :80 because it is the default HTTP port anyway*

**Finder->Go To-> /etc/**

Then open up the hosts file with TextEdit and do what I said above

Comment: Given that the OP is using a Mac OS X package, I don't think they'll find a hosts file there.

Comment: Sorry , I didn't read the question properly , fixed

Comment: There is absolutely no need to **replace** the `localhost` entry with something else; in fact, this is a bad idea and could break a lot of things.

Comment: Still not correct, the path is different on MacOS, and editing the file is not sufficient. Besides, I would advise very much against *replacing* the localhost entry, because a lot of programs depend on localhost being there.

Comment: I would not recommend replacing localhost - you could instead append another domain name for localhost.

Comment: did anyone mention that it's not a good idea to replace `localhost` ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use MAMP, but I have done the same thing using the pre-installed Apache 2.  There may be a simpler way to do this, but this has really helped me with testing multiple sites in my local machine.

### Edit host file

The host file is located at `/etc/hosts`.  I end all of my local test domains with `local`, but this isn't required.  Here's a sample of what I have.

```
# clients
    127.0.0.1       acmewidgets.clients.local
    127.0.0.1       someclient.clients.local
    127.0.0.1       etcetc.clients.local


# Projects and mini sites
    127.0.0.1       someproject.proj.local
    127.0.0.1       someotherproject.proj.local

# tools
    127.0.0.1   sql.tools.local

# Different open source solutions
    # e-commerce
        127.0.0.1       magento.apps.local
        127.0.0.1       opencart.apps.local
        127.0.0.1       oscommerce.apps.local
        127.0.0.1       zencart.apps.local
    # forums
        127.0.0.1       vanilla.apps.local
    # blogs
        127.0.0.1       wp.apps.local
        127.0.0.1       wpmu.apps.local
    # CMS's
        127.0.0.1       joomla.apps.local
        127.0.0.1       drupal.apps.local
        127.0.0.1       concrete5.apps.local
```

So not only do I have different client sites, but you can see that I have a subset of open source platforms that I routinely use and test against, as well as personal projects and tools.

Also, note that it's not a good idea to replace `localhost`, as some other applications are likely to use it.  You should just add

### Edit virtual hosts

Again, I don't use MAMP so I don't know where it's stored, but you're looking for the `http-vhosts.conf` file. In the standard OS X install, it's located at `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

For every *.local domain that I've created in my host file, I've created a respective virtual host entry.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

# Open source app testing
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName opencart.apps.local
    DocumentRoot /Users/justin/Development/localhost/opencart/html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName oscommerce.apps.local
    DocumentRoot /Users/justin/Development/localhost/oscommerce/html
</VirtualHost>

# Tools
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sql.tools.local
    DocumentRoot /Users/justin/Development/localhost/bin/tools/wwwsqldesigner
</VirtualHost>
```

* You may have to change the permissions on either of these files to be able to save your changes.